# Trace File Not found on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, marmalade

We are using the [Marmalade SDK](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade) for window's Mobile 6.5 development. We don't see the trace file **iwtrace.txt** on the root of the drive on which the application is installed. Is it require any setting to generate trace file? Please let us know..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you ensuring you are using a debug build. Trace files are only created in debug builds.